# submiting text in mysql works an embed code doesnt work

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess, post

when I'm trying to submit normal text everything works well but when I'm trying to submit a video embed code like from youtube it gives me that error:

```
Not Acceptable
An appropriate representation of the requested post.php could not be found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I've google that error 100 times already and some people say that i should edit the .htaccess file what i did more then 20 time in diferent ways but it never works when I'm trying to submit a embed code.

Comment: how can that be,, could you please provide the code , so we can know what exactly you are trying ? Your hosting service provider ?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="post.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <textarea name="video1" cols="106" rows="5"/></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
    </form>

my hoster is godaddy
and how i said it works only with normal text but not an embled code :/